# jQuery AJAX: Request failing everytime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple jQuery AJAX script which logs values to the console but every time AJAX value is undefined.

In **form.php** file is this:

```
if (empty($_POST['duration'])) return http_response_code(404);
```

Is there any option for how I can debug this? For now, I need to have it logged in the console but when I solve this the values will go to append in HTML file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#MainForm');
  var duration = $('#duration');

  form.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'form.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(res) {

      console.log(res.duration);

    }).fail(function(res) {

      console.log('not working');

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="MainForm" method="POST">
  <label>
            Duration
            <input id="duration" name="duration" type="number" step="0.1" value="">
        </label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you getting 'not working' in the console? If so, you can log 'res'. This will be the error that is generated.

Comment: @Wimanicesir im getting 'undefined'. If I change console.log(res.duration) to console.log(res) in console I get <empty string>.

Comment: No response return in form.php `if (empty($_POST['duration'])) return http_response_code(404);`

Comment: @Vel what do you mean?

Comment: It seems to be working: 404 triggers the `fail` callback.

Comment: @nitrin0 fail function runs when input is empty. Im getting in console undefined

Comment: What does your PHP code output when the duration is not empty? Where should `res.duration` come from?

Comment: @MatúšRebroš fail function runs when the AJAX request fails. Getting a 404 is a failure, that's why it runs. Like Vel said you're also not returning any content (just the 404 header) .

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? PHP code can be debugged simply through vardump, or better through XDebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.  `textStatus`, `httpStatus` added in ajax done response. you can check the http status.

**form.php**

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['duration'])){ 
    return http_response_code(404);
}else{
  echo $_POST['duration'];
}
?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#MainForm');
  var duration = $('#duration');

  form.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'form.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(res, textStatus, httpStatus) {

      console.log(httpStatus);

    }).fail(function(res) {

      console.log('not working');

    });

  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can using this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#MainForm');
  var duration = $('#duration');

  form.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'form.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(res, Status) {
    if(Status == "404"){
      // failed response.
    }

    }).fail(function() {
      console.log("failed");
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it